# Как запомнить переменную?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! При первом заходе на страницу выбирается вкладка номер 1 (инициализация). Дело осложняется тем, что на странице сделан пагинатор, который перезагружает страницу 
(он-то сделан в виде гиперссылок).

```
<span align="left"><strong> СОРТИРОВКА ПО :</strong></span> 
<span id="spantabs"><a href="#" onClick="set_mode_view(0);">Закладка 1</a></span>
<span id="spantabs"><a href="#" onClick="set_mode_view(1);">Закладка 2</a></span> 
<span id="spantabs"><a href="#" onClick="set_mode_view(4);">Закладка 5</a></span> 
//Инициализация 
<script> set_mode_view(0);</script>
```

Мне нужно как-то **запомнить номер выбранной закладки**. А то всё время после перезагрузки получается отрабатывает секция инициализация и, соответственно, выбирается закладка №1.

**Перенесено из ответа.**

Дело в том, что пагинация завязана на PHP и MySQL. Номер вкладки определяет способ сортировки результирующей таблицы. Грубо говоря, `SELECT * from table ORDER BY 'номер_вкладки'`. Так что одним JavaScript не обойтись. PHP-пагинатор вызывает перезагрузку страницы, но всё время выдаётся первая вкладка.

А как использовать глобальные переменные в JS, нигде нормально про это не рассказано? И ещё вопрос, можно ли получить адрес страницы путем JS или JQuery?

Comment: Свои пояснения лучше добавляйте в вопрос, а не в ответы.
А по теме: вчитайтесь в мой ответ. Глобальные переменные подойдут, только если страница НЕ перезагружается (как в моём примере, когда DOM строится на аяксе). И глобальная переменная в js - это объявленная не в пределах функций, а в самом файле со скриптами либо в блоке `<script></script>` в разметке.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант А: использовать анкоры. То есть, задавать href в виде "#0", "#1" и т.п., а потом разбирать адрес страницы и открывать нужную вкладку.
Вариант Б: использовать cookies. Тем более, что для них уже написаны [удобные функции](http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#3-2-i-1-getcookie-setcookie-deletecookie).

Comment: Еще есть третий вариант: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/16774/">history api</a>.

Comment: Якори подошли - хорошая штука!

Answer (score 0):

А я все такие вкладки-пагинацию полностью на аяксе делаю, нужные страницы храню в глобальных переменных javascript - и всё отлично работает как часы :)
А если переделывать не хочется - то варианты решения вам подсказал товарищ [[@ling](/users/1252/ling)](/users/1252/ling)

Comment: Вы наверно имели ввиду, что запрашиваете номер выбранной вкладки аяксом? И сохраняете в глобальные переменные. В противном случае, каким образом у вас сохраняются глобальные javascript переменные после перезагрузки страниц?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что всю рабочую область(контент - в зависимости от пагинации и фильтров) меняю аяксом, т.о. страница вообще не перезагружается(пока пользователь с неё не уйдёт). И раз страница не перезагружается - можно довольно-таки просто хранить все необходимые данные в глобальных переменных.